# Prisma using 1-1 and 1-n relation with same model

Tags: javascript, prisma

In this case, a ***Product*** has many ***Image***, and also has one main ***Image***.

But when i run `prisma format`，throw Error:

```
error: Error validating field `image` in model `Product`: The relation field `image` on Model `Product` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `ProductImage`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually.
```

my `schema.prisma`:

```
model ProductImage {
  id         String   @id @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(36)
  product_id String
  product    Product  @relation(fields: [product_id], references: [id])
  src        String   @db.VarChar(255)
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt

  @@map("product_image")
}

model Product {
  id         String         @id @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(36)
  image_id   String
  image      ProductImage   @relation(name: "main_image", fields: [image_id], references: [id])
  images     ProductImage[]
  slug       String         @unique(map: "slug") @db.VarChar(255)
  title      String         @db.VarChar(255)
  created_at DateTime       @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime       @default(now()) @updatedAt

  @@map("product")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This models should solve the issue:

```
model Product {
  id         String         @id @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(36)
  image_id   String         @unique
  // image   ProductImage   @relation(name: "main_image", fields: [image_id], references: [id])
  image      ProductImage   @relation(name: "main_image", fields: [image_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  images     ProductImage[]
  slug       String         @unique(map: "slug") @db.VarChar(255)
  title      String         @db.VarChar(255)
  created_at DateTime       @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime       @default(now()) @updatedAt

  @@map("product")
}

model ProductImage {
  id                 String    @id @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(36)
  src                String    @db.VarChar(255)
  created_at         DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at         DateTime  @default(now()) @updatedAt
  product_id         String
  product            Product   @relation(fields: [product_id], references: [id])
  product_main_image Product[] @relation("main_image")

  @@map("product_image")
}
```

These [references](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#the-relation-attribute) to relations in prisma schema should be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  
I try your code and new Error throwed:  
```Error validating: Reference causes a cycle. One of the @relation attributes in this cycle must have `onDelete` and `onUpdate` referential actions set to `NoAction`. Cycle path: ProductImage.product → Product.image. (Implicit default `onUpdate`: `Cascade`) Read more at https://pris.ly/d/cyclic-referential-actions```  
I fix this problem:  
```image      ProductImage   @relation(name: "main_image", fields: [image_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)```